# Npm workspaces: Different "main" property for development and publishing?

Tags: npm, package.json, workspace, monorepo, vite

I've created an npm workspace with two packages "foo" and "bar".
Furthermore, I'm using typescript so both packages contain a `src/index.ts`.

During development, I want to have the "main" property of both packages to be `src/index.ts`.
But after building and publishing the packages the "main" entry has to point to the built `dist/index.js`.

How can I accomplish that or is my assumption wrong, that I can point to the typescript file during development?
But then I would have to rebuild the packages during development all the time.
I hope that's not necessary.

Thank you for your help in advance

**UPDATE**
To be more precise, I need to have "main" point to the Typescript file `src/index.ts` because otherwise, I can't reference "foo" inside of "foo" itself:

```
// foo/src/index.ts
import { something } from 'foo';
```

This error is thrown:
`[vite:resolve] Failed to resolve entry for package "foo". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.`

The above import only works, If "main" points to `src/index.ts`.
Otherwise I would have to use relative paths to the imported file of the same project, for example

```
// foo/src/index.ts
import { something } from './someotherfile.ts';
```

Comment: I was looking into the same issue at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71014656/pnpm-workspace-dependency-and-also-supporting-publishing no response so far. Did you find a way to change it between development and publishing?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that vite needs the plugin vite-tsconfig-paths to find my main tsconfig.json to properly resolve the project:

```
// vite.config.ts
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

plugins: [
  tsconfigPaths({
    root: "../../",
  }),
],
```